# Can Hadoop do streaming?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, streaming, flume, stream-processing

Someone suggested that Hadoop does streaming, and have quoted Flume and Kafka as examples.

While I understand they might have streaming features, I wonder if they can be considered in the same league as stream processing technologies like Storm/Spark/Flink. Kafka is a 'publish-subscribe model messaging system' and Flume is a data ingestion tool. And even though they interact/integrae with hadoop are they technically part of 'hadoop' itself?

PS: I understand there is a [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) which is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is only YARN, HDFS, and MapReduce. As a project, it does not accommodate (near) real time ingestion or processing.

Hadoop Streaming is a tool used to manipulate data between *filesystem streams* (standard input/output)

Kafka is not only a publish/subscribe message queue.

**Kafka Connect** is essentially a Kafka channel, in Flume terms. Various plug-ins exist for reading from different "sources", producing to Kafka, then "sinks" exist to consume from Kafka to databases or filesystems. From a consumer perspective, this is more scalable than singular Flume agents deployed across your infrastructure. If all you're looking for log ingestion into Kafka, personally I find Filebeat or Fluentd to be better than Flume (no Java dependencies).

**Kafka Streams** is a comparable product to Storm, Flink, and Samza, except the dependency upon YARN or any cluster scheduler doesn't exist, and it's possible to embed a Kafka Streams processor within any JVM compatible application (for example, a Java web application). You'd have difficulties trying to do that with Spark or Flink without introducing a dependency on some external system(s).

The only benefits of Flume, NiFi, Storm, Spark, etc. I find is that they **compliment** Kafka and they have *Hadoop compatible* integrations along with other systems used in the BigData space like Cassandra (see `SMACK` stack)

So, to answer the question, you need to use other tools to allow streaming data to be processed and stored by Hadoop.